# An error occurred when verifying security for the message. SOAP

Tags: java, webservice

Estoy tratando de firmar el request que se le debe enviar al servicio de la DIAN para la entrega de facturas, pero el servicio me responde: An error occurred when verifying security for the message
Cuando lo hago por SOAPUI funciona, pero desde codigo con java NO.
Estoy utilizando javax.xml.crypto.dsig.XMLSignature 
Sera que me pueden ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Recuerda siempre agregar el codigo que hiciste, si no, imposible saber que error estas cometiendo. usa el boton [edit] y agrega el codigo